# Sending name of file to be installed by server with button click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My webpage displays a list of files on the server and next to filename is an "install" button. When I click "install", the server should recieve name of the corresponsing file to be installed. My current code is not able to psas name of the file to server. Can you please suggest how to send name of file to server on button click ?

Here is my code

```js
app.controller('RdaController', ['$scope', 'RdaService',
  function($scope, RdaService) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello world";

    $scope.file = "installJob.zip";
    $scope.sendToCTP = function($scope) {
      return RdaService.SendFileToCTP($scope);
    };
  }
]);


app.service('RdaService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    this.SendFileToCTP = function($scope) {
      return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "../api/CTP/installJobFromFile/" + $scope.file,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).success(function(data) {
        //$scope.sendToCTP = data;
        console.log(data);
      }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<h2>List of Files available</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat="file in listOfFiles">
    <td>{{ file }}</td>
    <td><span class="btn-group" role="group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sendToCTP(file)">install</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">delete</button></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass the `$scope` to a service. You can however pass the fileName directly. Try this:

```
app.controller('RdaController', ['$scope', 'RdaService',
  function($scope, RdaService) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello world";

    $scope.file = "installJob.zip";
    $scope.sendToCTP = function(file) {
      return RdaService.SendFileToCTP(file);
    };
  }
]);


app.service('RdaService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    this.SendFileToCTP = function(file) {
      return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "../api/CTP/installJobFromFile/" + file,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).success(function(data) {

        console.log(data);
      }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

And your HTML looks okay to work with this. If you need to perform any action after $http returns, you can do that with a .then() on the `RdaService.SendFileToCTP` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.service('RdaService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    this.SendFileToCTP = function(filename) {
      return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "../api/CTP/installJobFromFile/" + filename,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // DONT FORGET TO RETURN DATA HER
        return data ;
      }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return null ;
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

To get the result of $http promise you have to use  `RdaService.SendFileToCTP($scope.file).then()` like this :

```
app.controller('RdaController', ['$scope', 'RdaService',
  function($scope, RdaService) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello world";

    $scope.file = "installJob.zip";
    $scope.sendToCTP = function($scope.file) {
        RdaService.SendFileToCTP($scope.file).then(function (res) {
            // HER you can use the result of your callback on $http 
            console.log(res);
            $scope.result = res ; // for exemple
        });
    };
  }
]);
```